# Filtering for Duplicated Names with Conditional Statements in R - Reprex

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large database where there are rows that are partially duplicated. I'm trying to use a filter in dplyr with conditional statements to remove these partially duplicated rows.

**Goal:** I want to remove all rows where there are duplicate combinations of a1 and id1 with var1 equaling 0. To achieve this, I tried using a duplicated() call in my filter function along with conditional statements.

**Issues:** The code below I've used below seems to ignore the last condition of var1 equaling zero. I tried two different ways of filtering to get the desired results to no avail. Is there something wrong with my duplicated() call? Should I use distinct() instead?

```
library(dplyr)
a1 <- c('adam', 'adam', 'adam', 'megan', 'megan', 'megan', 'jen', 'jen', 'jen')
id1 <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c')
var1 <- as.numeric(c('0', '3.2', '3', '2.2', '1.1', '0', '1.2', '2.4','3.1'))
test_df <- data.frame(a1, id1, var1)

#code to get rid of duplicates
test_df2 <- test_df %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(id1) & duplicated(a1) & var1 == 0))

#alternative code
test_df3 <- test_df
test_df3$new_id <- with(test_df3, paste0(a1, sep = "-", id1))

test_df3 <- test_df3 %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(new_id) & var1 == 0))
```

Here's a pic of what I'm getting:
[image: Example of Errant Return]

Here's the desired result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the question by using Janitor's get_dupes and then doing a filter from that subset. I'm not sure why I cant achieve this using conditional statements in dplyr, but this is a hack that works well enough.

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

a1 <- c('adam', 'adam', 'adam', 'megan', 'megan', 'jen', 'jen', 'jen')
id1 <- c('a', 'b', 'a','a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a')
var1 <- as.numeric(c('3.2', '2.7', '0','2', '1.1', '0', '2.2','3.1'))
var2 <- as.numeric(c('3.4', '3', '0','1.7', '1.2', '3', '0','3.3'))
test_df <- data.frame(a1, id1, var1, var2)
test_df$a1_id1 <- with(test_df, paste0(a1, sep = "-", id1))

#get all instances where there is a duplicated name and id
test_df2 <- test_df %>%
  get_dupes(a1_id1)

#remove rows that have var1 as 0 and remove column called dupe_count
test_df3 <- test_df2 %>%
  filter(var1 != 0) %>%
  select(-dupe_count)

#Remove all instances of duplicate names
test_df4 <- test_df %>%
  group_by(a1_id1) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)

#combine the two df's created and bind together for the desired output.
test_df_updated <- dplyr::bind_rows(test_df3, test_df4)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
librar(dplyr)
test_df %>% 
  group_by(a1, id1) %>% 
  summarise(var1 = sum(var1))
```

```
 a1    id1    var1
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 adam  a       3.2
2 adam  b       3  
3 jen   a       1.2
4 jen   b       2.4
5 jen   c       3.1
6 megan a       2.2
7 megan b       1.1
```

Comment: Thank you @Tarjae - This is a helpful alternative. While this works for my reprex it doesn't necessarily work for my database because I have additional columns of variables that can't be summed.

Is there a way to omit rows based on the filter criteria?